Как вывести ArrayList<String> в Mustache?
Допустим, у меня есть объект с именем WB, и этот объект включает ArrayList с именем result. В моем контроллере Spring Boot WB представлен как ("WB",WB). В шаблоне Mustache WB представлен как показано внизу, и все работает нормально:
{{#WB}}
{{someStringObjectFromWB}}
{{/WB}}

Но, я не знаю как итерировать мой ArrayList ("result") таким же образом (если это возможно), как:
{{#WB}}
{{result}}
{{/WB}}

Пожалуйста, помогите.
Я пытался сделать что-то вроде этого, но это не работает:
{{#WB}}
{{#result}}{{.}} {{/result}}
{{/WB}}

Код контроллера:
@PostMapping (/getResult)
public String res (Map<String,Object>stat){    
  WB wb= WB.calc();    
  stat.put("wb",wb);    
}

Обычные объекты String,  Integer  выводит без проблем через имя переменной. А вот как выводить списки не понимаю.
Вот файл Mustache:
{{#wb}}
     {{#result}}            
     <ul>{{item}}</ul>                 
     {{/result}}            
{{/wb}}


Добавьте код контроллера в вопрос.

@RomanC готово, можешь смотреть

@RomanC очень прошу помочь, уже целый день потратил на это ((

А где у тебя списки в контроллере?

@RomanC список в объекте WB , я просто думал нужно в шаблонизаторе  указать как и для других данных название  переменной ArrayList в объекте WB.  Но я пробовал так же добавить stat.put ("result", wb.getResult()) --  не работает . ( getResult возращает список если что)

@RomanC  добавил еще файл mustache (основную структуру)

Попробуй следующий шаблон
{{#WB.result}}
{{.}} 
{{/WB.result}}

Если result является свойством обьекта wb, то для доступа к нему нужно использовать . (Selection). Ну, а далее используется #(Section) для того, чтобы вывести список объектов.
